# "Only then is the survival brain turned down and the personality fever cooled."

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the author omit *that* between *is* and *the*? Are the verbs about *turned down* and *cooled* in the subjunctive?

> The Buddha taught that kind of happiness. He put it this way: “True happiness can only be found by eliminating the false idea of ‘I’ or ‘self.’” **Only then is the survival brain turned down and the personality fever cooled.** The only problem with that formulation is that once the “I” or “self ” has been eliminated, then there is no one around to enjoy the feeling of happiness.
>   (Excerpt from [*Crazy Wisdom Saves the World Again!*](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=wU2HzHjzWdwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Wes "Scoop" Nisker.)

Comment: my fault... I ask a wrong question ... let me edit it ...it's not "Does the author omit the "that" between "the" and "survival"?" , but "Does the author omit the "that" between "is" and "the"?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the author omit *that* between *is* and *the*?

No. This is a sentence in which the phrase "only then" has been shifted to the front of the sentence, for emphasis and to put it next to the referent of *then*, which refers to when the false idea is eliminated.

```
The survival brain is turned down and the personality fever cooled only then.
                                                                       ↓
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ↓ 
Only then is the survival brain turned down and the personality fever cooled.
```

> Are the verbs about *turned down* and *cooled* in the subjunctive?

No. They are in the passive:

```
The survival brain is turned down.  
The personality fever [is] cooled.
```

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for editing to keep us talking about the same thing!

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for editing my question too. But as an non-native speaker , I think writing  it as  “that” would be better than writing  it as _that_ , because the readers can find out the point easier.

Comment: @Lincoln Use of italics for "mentioned" terms is the established convention in discussion of grammar, and we mostly follow that convention here.